# How To Toggle Message Using React (Test-Dome Solution1)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The Message component contains an anchor element and a paragraph below the anchor. Rendering of the paragraph should be toggled by clicking on the anchor element using the following logic:

At the start, the paragraph should not be rendered.
After a click, the paragraph should be rendered.
After another click, the paragraph should not be rendered.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution could be simplified a bit by only hiding the paragraph when the state is false and not changing the entire return value.

```
class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: 0
    };
  }

  clickHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.state.visible
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
          Want to buy a new car?
        </a>
        {this.state.visible && <p>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'> </div>";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Also you could replace the <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> with <></>, to make the code a little bit cleaner, but I'm not sure if it works in every React configuration

Comment: this is an extra syntax, and it can not have key prop, better to use React.Fragment

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I used to pass the test cases

```
class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: 1
    };
  }

  clickHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.state.visible
    });
  };
  render() {
    return this.state.visible ? (
      <React.Fragment>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
          Want to buy a new car?
        </a>

      </React.Fragment>
    ) : (
      <React.Fragment>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
          Want to buy a new car?
        </a>
        <p>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'> </div>";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);
```